# horizontal legend at the bottom of graph in jqplot

Tags: jqplot, legend

I m able to get horizontal legend of jqplot  graph using EnhancedLegendRenderer plugin.But i need horizontal legend at the bottom of the graph .Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

You should always show some work when posting to stack overflow. It helps us understand your problem.

I *think* you are having a problem with [EnhancedLedgendRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html) based on your description.

This is what my code looks like to achieve a 1 row, 3 column legend.

```
          legend: {
        // This renderer is needed for advance legends.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
        show: true, 
        location: 's', 
        placement: 'outside',
        // Breaks the ledgend into horizontal.
        rendererOptions: {
          numberRows: '1',
          numberColumns: '3'
        },
        seriesToggle: true
      },
```

Also, you are probably getting down voted because of punctuation and lack of capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

change placement option to outside to outsideGrid

```
legend: {
    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
    show: true, 
    location: 's', 
    placement: 'outsideGrid',
    rendererOptions: {
      numberRows: '1',
    },
  },
```